# Authenticode signing - only sign my assemblies

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, code-signing, authenticode

I have a .Net solution with the following structure:

- a.exe
- b.dll
- thirdParty.dll

**I wish to Authenticode sign just my own binaries (a.exe and b.dll).**

I currently have a post-build event on the csproj file for a.exe:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe" sign /t http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll /a $(TargetPath)
for %%f in ("$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)*.dll") do "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe" sign /t http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll /a $(TargetPath) %%f
```

However, this will sign all dll's including thirdParty.dll and also runs the risk of trying to sign any un-managed DLL's.

Now the simplest solution would be to put a post-build event on the csproj file for b.dll and remove the for loop shown above. However, in practical terms we have many assemblies and will likely add more. I don't want to rely on other developers remembering to add a post-build step to Authenticode sign any new assemblies.

I can use a PowerShell script described [here](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/12/26/how-to-strong-name-partially-signed-assemblies/) to only sign managed assemblies, but that would still sign thirdParty.dll in the above example.

How do I enumerate and sign just the assemblies containing my own code?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I enumerate and sign just the assemblies containing my own code?

You can use "`if..else if`" in your loop statement to exclude the `thirdParty.dll`:

To test this, I have created test sample with below post-build event:

```
for %%f in ("$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)*.dll") do ( if not "%%~nf"=="thirdParty" (echo %%~nf))
```

You can use your sign command：

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe" sign /t http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll /a $(TargetPath)
```

instead of test command `echo %%~nf`.

Besides, if you have multiple thirdParty.dll files that need to be excluded, you can use superimposed `if` statement:

```
for %%f in ("$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)*.dll") do ( if not "%%~nf"=="thirdParty1" (if not "%%~nf"=="thirdParty2" ( echo %%~nf)))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but we rely on multiple third party libraries. This solution has effectively the same problem that we'd need to remember to manually update the post-build script for every new library.

Comment: @Tom, you need remember to manually to update the post-build scripts for the third Party new library not every new library. Looks like you have to do that, because Visual Studio not smart enough to know which dll file is third party libray.